# Javascript - Intern - Windows is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, javascript-objects, intern

I am running my intern test using the following code

```
node node_modules/intern/runner.js config=tests/intern
```

on my local machine. The application is using Dojo.
Basically I am trying to override the window.alert function as one of my test is failing because of unexpected alert.

```
window.alert = function(msg) {
    //override alert function
    //...
}
```

I tried putting this in my intern test and got the error. After some search I learned that window object is not available on node environment. Where can I override the alert?
 The `intern file` looks like

```
define(['intern/lib/args'], function(args) {
    var DEFAULT_PORT = "8080";

    var urlInfo = {
        PORT: args.port || DEFAULT_PORT,
        BASE_URL : "http://localhost:".concat(args.port || DEFAULT_PORT, "/webtest"),
    };

    var config = {
        proxyPort: 9000,

        proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',

        capabilities: {
            'selenium-version': '2.45.0',
        },

        ...
        ...
    };

    return config;
});
```

Intern Test file example

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil',
    'intern',
    'intern/dojo/node!fs'
], function(registerSuite, assert, Pages, intern, fs) {

    registerSuite ({
        name: 'Tests',

        setup: function() {
            window.alert = function(msg){
                console.log("Unexpected Alert: "+msg);
            }
            return this.remote.get(require.toUrl( intern.config.functionalInfo.BASE_URL)).maximizeWindow();
        },

        beforeEach: function() {
            return    
        },

        afterEach: function() {
            return 
        },

        'Test1' : function() {
             this.timeout = 600000;
            return this.remote
              .setFindTimeout(5000)
              ....
           },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`window` does not exist in node, you have to override its `alert` from code that runs on the browser (the code being tested), not on node itself. I would do it in the setup code for each test that uses it.

Comment: when you say the code that runs on browser, do you mean the intern test itself?

Comment: what if I was using grunt to run the test, in that case would it still not work ?

Comment: @8785krs, grunt runs on node so the window object will still not be defined

Comment: @juan Mendes. by setup code do you mean the setup function in the intern test ? I tried putting it in there but it still gives the same error

Comment: In functional tests, anything within the test module itself, with the exception of functions passed to `execute` or `executeAsync`, is still executed in Node.js.